# Real Time SMS using SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms

Hello: I am working in a financial organization where I would like to send real time account balance and transaction information to customers. Does SFMC has provision to have API integration where I can send mobile phone number and send SMS to customers?

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: [**MobileConnect**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/getting_started_with_mobileconnect/) and the [**MobileConnect API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm).

You have several options to sending SMS out of Marketing Cloud.  Here are some use-cases described on [**this page**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/mobileconnect_use_cases/):

- Sending Transactional SMS Alerts
- Sending Automated Dynamic Marketing Messages
- Enabling Web-Based Opt-In to MobileConnect Messages
- Data-Based Sending
- Providing Information to Conference Attendees via SMS and Email Messages
- Capturing Customer Information and Sending an Offer
- Creating a Survey with Multiple Questions
- Offering Coupon Codes via AMPscript in MobileConnect